# Converting PDF to Powerpoint, importing each slide as a singular picture

Tags: ms-office, pdf

I have the ability to export a PDF as a powerpoint slide through Adobe Acrobat, but the image quality and font selection suffers because it is trying to convert each component into a modifiable element.

All I want is to treat the entire page as an image and batch import each of the pictures into a powerpoint slide without sacrificing resolution.  I don't need to modify any of the content.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Similar question on TeX.SE: [conversion - Export beamer slides to powerpoint/openoffice-impress/keynote editable format - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21986/export-beamer-slides-to-powerpoint-openoffice-impress-keynote-editable-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use web services such as [Zamzar to convert your PDF to PPT](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=zamzar%20pdf%20to%20ppt) directly, but the downside is lack of privacy and watermark on your PPT.

It is better to split the process into two steps:

1. Export PDF into images
2. Import images into PPT

### Export PDF into JPG using Preview

macOS' Preview has built in functionality to export your PDF into PNGs. Once you have your PDF open in Preview,

1. Choose View > Thumbnails or press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
2. Select all the pages you want to export, click on File > Export
3. Select JPG format and the appropriate quality

### Use ImageMagick

If you have ImageMagick installed, use a similar command as

```
magick -density 200 -trim input.pdf -quality 100 -flatten output-%02d.jpg
```

assuming the PDF is created with 200 dpi. You can adjust the density and scaling accordingly to create the best quality image. See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605085/399759).

Note: Imagemagick uses Ghostscript in the background. You can use Ghostscript directly but the syntax is not as user-friendly. For example:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r200 -dJPEGQ=100 -sOutputFile=output-%02d.jpg input.pdf -dBATCH
```

### Import Images into Powerpoint

Open up a new Presentation in Powerpoint and click Insert > Photo Album

[image: Powerpoint Insert Album]

Select all the images and click **Create**

[image: Powerpoint create album]

And now you the PDF content is imported into Powerpoint

[image: Imported powerpoint images]

Comment: Thanks so much for this amazingly extensive answer.  Unfortunately, the Mac version of Powerpoint does not have "photo album" functionality.  Sorry for not specifying I was on a Mac before (I had just assumed, given the forum we're on).  Do you have any idea for Macs?

Comment: Unfortunately Mac for Powerpoint do not have the functionality to import a Photo album or multiple images https://support.office.com/en-us/article/photo-albums-aren-t-available-in-powerpoint-for-mac-1db1a051-c3bc-4e42-9e93-304f62fa9a9c . You can use Automator https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VEdJvVOOLY or http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00050_BATCH_IMPORT_images_into_PowerPoint.htm .

Comment: How about using Keynote instead? Drag all the images in Finder and drop them into the Slides column. You can then export into PPT format

Comment: ```magick: no images found for operation `-trim' at CLI arg 3 @ error/operation.c/CLIOption/5311.```

Comment: [here](https://superuser.com/a/680781/1801252) a bit more detail about the use of *Ghostscript* to convert multipage document

Comment: @Parseltongue On Mac you can use *LibreOffice Impress* which have a [Photo Album Plugin](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/photo-album-gui) (I hope it's available on Mac too...) and after save as PPTX ([bit of details here](https://askubuntu.com/a/901288/1571456))

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one page you can open the PDF in Preview and then export the file as a jpeg. See image below.

[image]

Then you can paste the image into Powerpoint.

If the PDF is more than one page open it in Preview and select Thumbnails. Select each thumbnail and export it as a jpeg. Continue as I explained above.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you cannot convert the PDF file to PowerPoint without losing the quality of the picture, especially if you created the PDF file in the older versions. If you don't want to lose the picture quality is better to create a new PowerPoint presentation. If you need some unique templates instead of using the default PowerPoint design, visit this site https://okslides.com. On-site, you can find multiple great design templates, and they are all compatible with the older PowerPoint versions. I always use templates from their site because I wouldn't say I like default templates.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But it's possible: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665611/250119